# How does closures see context variables into the stack?

Tags: python, stack, closures, programming-languages

I would like to understand how the stack frame pushed by calling `b()` can access the value of `x` that lives in the stack frame pushed by `a()`.

Is there a pointer from `b()` frame to `a()` frame? Or does the runtime copy the value of `x` as a local variable in the `b()` frame? Or is there another machanism under the hood?

This example is in python, but is there a universal mechanism to solve that or different languages use different mechanisms?

```
>>> def a():
...     x = 5
...     def b():
...         return x + 2
...     return b()
... 
>>> a()
7
```

Comment: There is no universal mechanism. I suggest watching recent [mCoding video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXugs4B3lwU) on that very topic in Python. In short, at compile time, Python decides in what scope the variable will be looked up. In our case, since `x` is not assigned to in `b`, we check an outer function - it is there, so Python "knows" to look up value of `x` in `a` whenever we need it in `b`. Then, when we actually reach call to `b` Python looks it up in `a` scope.

Answer (score 1):

In CPython (the implementation most people use) `b` itself contains a reference to the value. Consider this modification to your function:

```
def a():
    x = 5
    def b():
        return x + 2

    # b.__closure__[0] corresponds to x
    print(b.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
    x = 9
    print(b.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
```

When you call `a`, note that the value of the cell content changes with the local variable `x`.

The `__closure__` attribute is a tuple of `cell` objects, one per variable that `b` closes over. The `cell` object basically has one interesting attribute, `cell_contents`, that acts like a reference to the variable it represents. (You can even *assign* to the `cell_contents` attribute to change the value of the variable, but I can't imagine when that would be a good idea.)

Comment: Documentation states: "“Cell” objects are used to implement variables referenced by multiple scopes. For each such variable, a cell object is created to store the value; the local variables of each stack frame that references the value contains a reference to the cells from outer scopes which also use that variable."

Comment: Then, I understand that a cell object is created outside the stack (heap) and both, frame a() and b() have local references (pointers) to it (instead of values). When I call a(), and a() subsequently calls b(), after b() return and go out of scope, b()'s reference to the cell is destroyed, and the same occurs with the a()'s reference to the cell when it go out of scope. It's right?

Comment: `a` itself does not have a reference, like `b` does. The code for `a` has an instruction to *create* `x` when `a` is executed.